# conversion of regular expression to automata

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I've a task to specify a finite automata (of any kind) that accepts the language described by this regular expression: $a(bab)^+b^*|(ab)^*(aa)^+$

My first solution looks like this:
[image]

I would like to know if I'm reading this expression correctly:

1. First we have $a$ and since sequence $(bab)^+$ has to occur at least once then we can skip an additional Epsilon between them
2. Then we have alternate route between sequences $b^*$ and $(ab)^*$ (is it correct that I'm using Epsilon for sequence $(ab)^*$? or maybe it should be presented in a below manner:
   [image])
3. After each of them we have to go through last one which is $(aa)^+$ (and again skipping Epsilon because we have to go through it at least once).

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Understanadable, have a great day :) and hopefully this question will be more useful to other visitors.